# packing numbers of the unit balls in Euclidean spaces and the dimensions

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering, configuration-spaces, sphere-packing

Let $k$,  $m$  and  $n$  be   positive integers.  Let $r$ be a positive real number.

The $n$-th ordered  $r$-disk configuration space on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{mk}$ is

$$
F_r(\mathbb{R}^{mk}, n)=\Big\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in \underbrace{ \mathbb{R}^{mk}\times \mathbb{R}^{mk}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^{mk}}_n~~\Big  |~~||x_i||_{\mathbb{R}^{mk}}\leq 1 {\rm~~for~any~~}1\leq i\leq n {\rm~~and}~~ d_{\mathbb{R}^{mk}}(x_i,x_j)\geq 2r {\rm~~for~any~~} 1\leq i<j\leq n\Big\}. 
$$

Let $N(r,m,k)$  be the largest  integer $n$  such that $F_r(\mathbb{R}^{mk}, n)\neq  \emptyset$.

Fix $r$ and $m$.

**Question.** Whether is it true or not that $N(r,m,k_1)^{1/k_1}\leq  N(r,m,k_2)^{1/k_2}$  for any $k_1>k_2$?

**Question.** If the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty} N(r,m,k)^{1/k}$ exists,  how to compute or estimate the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty} N(r,m,k)^{1/k}$?

**Question.** Suppose in addition, $r$  is  sufficiently small. For example, $r=0.0001$, $r=0.001$. Are there  any results or methods for  $\lim_{k\to\infty} N(r,m,k)^{1/k}$?

Are there any such references? Thank you very much.

Comment: To be clear, this is value is only a function of the dimension $d=mk$, correct? I find the separation of variables somewhat strange to think about in this context versus a function $N(r,d)$.

Comment: Yes, Prof. @RavenclawPrefect